# How to speed up git pulling triggered using jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, msbuild

This is a xamarin mobile application of size more than 2 GB.
My lead was able to build it using MSBuild.
I am given the task of automating the build using Jenkins with MSBuild as plugin.
Since this is a very big application, git pulling has already taken more than one hour and the task progress bar is showing around 95%.

```
Question 1) How can I speed up this jenkins/git pulling process?
```

I am working on the client's virtual machine and internet speed is fairly good

I am sharing my jenkins console here
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. shallow clone

   You can specify `--depth=<n>` for `git clone`. The point is to reduce the data to be fetched. This does not work well for a repository that has new binary files added continously.
2. reference clone

   First make a full clone as the reference repository in a directory which the jenkins job can access. Then add `--reference <path_of_the_reference_repository>` for `git clone`. Update the reference repository regularly, maybe twice a week or so, depending on your needs. The point is to reuse any data that already exist in the reference repository, only to fetch the data that don't exist locally.

Comment: 1. While shallowing, how do I know what depth(n) to set? Is it okay to give depth as 'n'. If not, how do I decide?      When using bash scripting to clone, Its pretty much quick. But, takes hell of a time when doing with jenkins. Is this because my job configurations are wrong?                                                               2.I have tried giving reference repositories. But, how do I make sure that jenkins is accessing from reference repositories. Is there any means i can check this? Thank you once again

Comment: @SRKprakash it depends on how many levels of logs you need. If you need only the latest code, n=1 is enough. If you need to get the diff, then at least n=2. You could have a try with different depth, and run `git log` and `git show` to see the differences.

Comment: how do I make sure that jenkins is accessing from my reference repositories. Is there any means to check this?

Comment: how do I make sure that jenkins is accessing from my reference repositories. Is there any means to check this? I am asking this because these configurations doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: @SRKprakash you could try it in the build script if the plugin does not support such configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fast local network but a slow internet network, you can keep a copy of the checkout on your local network somewhere, and have your build copy it into your workspace and run "git pull" followed by "git checkout BRANCH".  This is not ideal because you lose the "changes" between builds, but if that's not important for you, that may do the trick.  Another idea would be to NOT delete the workspace, and simply do a "clean before checkout".  Ideally, you want to do what @ElpieKay suggested though.  I'm just throwing out an alternative.