# How to get latest commit on a branch without checking out files using Jenkins git plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to develop a CI groovy pipeline in jenkins for one of our repo. The repo is huge (around 18+ GB). Checkout takes around 2/3 hours. I need to retrieve the latest commit on a branch in repo and trigger some tests (in already checked-out area).

Any idea how can i use Jenkins git plugin to get latest commit without actually checking out files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47011025/7976758

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--depth 1` option to clone the last state of the repo without history:

```
git clone --depth 1 <path to the repo>
```